# How to use Comparable interface in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, j2mepolish

Hey hi friends I am going to use Comparable interface in j2me but it showing error on line Comparable interface, which import statement need to be write or how to remove this error from j2me class. please help me

```
public class DFTpair implements  Comparable{
```

its showing red line on Comparable
Thnks

Comment: @Sajid: post your error message.

Comment: @Sajid: did you implement compareTo() method?

Comment: ya i am have implemented that method

Comment: Error- Can not find Class Comparable

Comment: @Sajid: `Comparable interface does not exist in CLDC`. I just googled `Can not find Class Comparable j2me`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to develop on J2ME platform it's good idea to get documentation for API you need. The most popular profiles and configurations (all versions of MIDP and CLDC) don't have this interface. So if you want this interface you have to create it by yourself.

And what do you need Comparable for?

Comment: Hey Hi thanks for suggestion, I am going to compare two wave file amplitude so i need this interface...